# LCM of two products

Tags: number-theory, least-common-multiple

Is LCM(a*b, c*d) = LCM(LCM(a,c), LCM(b,d))?

If not, is there a way to simplify the LHS?

Comment: $LCM(2*2,2*2)=4$, but $LCM(LCM(2,2),LCM(2,2))=LCM(2,2)=2$

Comment: Well LCM(a, b) = ab/GCD(a,b) so

LCM(LCM(a,c), LCM(b,d)) = LCM(ac/gcd(a,c), bd/gcd(b, d)) = [abcd/gcd(a,c)gcd(b,d)]/gcd(ac/gcd(a,c),bd/gcd(b, d))   I don't know if that counts as simpler.

Answer (score 2):

if you take $a=b=c=d$ the assertion fails